# Velocity as a result of instantaneous force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

A particle with mass $m$ has force with magnitude $F$ applied to it in the positive $x$ direction at time $t = 0$ and for all $t > 0$ the magnitude of the force equals $0$. What velocity $v$ will the particle travel at assuming no frictional force or loss of energy due to internal friction etc.?

Comment: This is not a good question as it is not clear from the question what actually happens.  Usually when a statement is made about a force acting at an instant of time and then never again there is the implication that an impulse has been applied to the system and the change in momentum of the system would be equal to the impulse.  If this question implies that the force is applied for an instant of time then that is a physical impossibility.

Comment: As @Farcher points out, this is a physical impossibility.   This is not a valid physics question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The impulse is zero. Hence the change in momentum is zero. The particle will remain at rest.